# Hibernate: referencedColumnName in JoinColumn being ignored

Tags: hibernate, join, mapping, joincolumn

I have two tables FOO (containing a reference to an entry in BAR) and BAR mapped as below:

Foo.class:

```
@Id
@Column(name="ID", unique=true, nullable=false)
public BigDecimal getId() {
    return id;
}

@Column(name="BARREF", unique=true, nullable=false)
public String getBarRef() {
    return this.barRef;
}

@OneToOne(mappedBy="foo") //Inverse of the relationship
public Foo getFoo() {
    return this.foo;
}

... + other columns (including other mapped classes) ...
```

Bar.class:

```
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="REF", updatable=false, insertable=false, referencedColumnName="BARREF")   //Owner of the relationship
public Foo getFoo() {
    return this.foo;
}

@Column(name="NAME")
public String getName() {
    return this.name;
}

... + other columns ...
```

When executing the HQL:

```
select bar.name from Foo foo left outer join Bar bar
```

The sql generated is

```
select bar.NAME from FOO foo left outer join BAR bar on foo.ID = bar.REF
```

Where as I'm looking for the SQL to be:

```
select bar.NAME from FOO foo left outer join BAR bar on foo.BARREF = bar.REF
```

Is there a reason why referencedColumnName seems to be ignored (and therefore the default PK is being used). Does it have to refer to an ID column?

This is the only table that doesn't map by the ID column, I experimented with having both ID and BARREF as ID columns but I get the error:
'wrong number of columns. should be 2'

I have to use HQL for this query due to a limitation with Criteria and cannot alter the database schema.

Comment: Did you find a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

try using the sql query you wanted as the hql query of your code

Comment: unfortunately I get `unexpected token: on`. If i change the SQL slightly to `select bar.NAME from FOO foo left outer join BAR bar with foo.ID = bar.REF` I get `with-clause referenced two different from-clause elements`.